# Declaring a CLOB in an Oracle database with a custom charset

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, clob

Is it possible to declare a UTF-8 CLOB if the database is set up with the following character sets?

```
PARAMETER               VALUE
NLS_CHARACTERSET        CL8ISO8859P5
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
```

I tried passing a charset name to the declaration, but it looks like it can only accept references to character sets of other objects.

```
declare
  clob_1 clob character set "AL32UTF8";
begin
  null;
end;
```

/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, see [PL/SQL Language Fundamentals](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS002)

> PL/SQL uses the **database character set** to represent:
>
> - Stored source text of PL/SQL units
> - Character values of data types CHAR, VARCHAR2, CLOB, and LONG

So, in your case you have to use `NCLOB` which uses `AL16UTF16` or try a workaround with `BLOB`. However, this might become cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can't do that.

Database character set is defined during database creation (and can't be changed unless you recreate the database) and all *character* datatype columns store data in that character set.

Perhaps you could try with `NCLOB` data type, where "N" represents "national character set" and it'll store Unicode character data.

> Unicode is a universal encoded character set that can store
>   information in any language using a single character set